# OpenCL Parallelization Cost

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I benched a Freescale i.MX6.Q platform for OpenCL and I got interesting results about it I cannot totally explain. My algorithm is done by executing 4 kernels and the last one is the one interesting me here: a classic image difference.

I tested two version, a vectorized one and a classic one (without vectorization). At first I was surprised by the results a parallelized difference gave: on this platform, OpenCL have to be chosen only the image to process contains more than 180kpix (in the algorithm, images are processed as buffers).

However for both OpenCL implementation there were constants execution times (around 5ms) at the beginning (for small images). I checked the execution times for an empty kernel and they are always around 5ms on this platform for any images tested (from 32x32 to 1920x1024).

I see these times for an empty kernel as the parallelization cost for an OpenCL difference and I wanted to know what that cost contains ?

My kernel compilation is done outside the bench and I dont see which step should take 5ms. Is it only the NDRange interpretation the GPU is processing ?

If someone has explanations for this, I take it !!!

Baptiste

EDIT :

My time measurement and kernel launch :

```
start_time = time_now();

cl_mem_flags mem_device_host;
if (device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_HOST_UNIFIED_MEMORY>()==CL_TRUE)
    mem_device_host = CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR;
else
    mem_device_host = CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR;

cl_status = kernel.setArg(0, input_image);
oclReturnOnError(cl_status, "Passage de l'argument 0 du kernel 'morph'")

cl_status = kernel.setArg(1, output_image);
oclReturnOnError(cl_status, "Passage de l'argument 1 du kernel 'morph'")

cl_status = kernel.setArg(2, input_SE);
oclReturnOnError(cl_status, "Passage de l'argument 2 du kernel 'morph'")

cl::Event eventMorph;
cl_status = commandQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel,
    cl::NullRange,
    global_range,
    local_range
    NULL , &eventMorph);
oclReturnOnError(cl_status, "Ajout du kernel 'morph' à la queue de commande")

cl_status = eventMorph.wait();
oclReturnOnError(cl_status, "Attende d'exécution du kernel 'morph'")

end_time = time_now();
```

Comment: Could you provide some code of the launch/measurement? Since 5ms it is a very high value. As an example, in my setup I have like 1us of executing overhead.

Comment: I add an example. I measure the kernel execution and the arguments settings. For my empty kernel, I have only 1 arguments and several compilation option to have a kernel close to my difference. But my setup is kinda poor I think (CPU 4 cores @ 1GHz and GPU 64 cores in 4 CU @ 500MHz) without local memory

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is mainly how you are meassuring your kernel execution. Using the OS time_now() will give you poor resolution, and is not the way to test OpenCL performance.

Additionally the host is slow attending the GPU work-load. So, if you queue, don't force a execution (with `clFlush()`) and then passively wait for completion, the result is a very poor perceived performance. Since you have to wait for all the queues and submits, so you will see a lot of overhead between your call and the real execution.

That model of run+wait is valid for examples and demos, but should not be used for a real system or for performance measurements.

The proper way to **measure the performance** is using the `event`. You can use `cl::Event.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>()` and `cl::Event.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>()` to measure the start and end times of your kernel.

The proper way to **run the system**, is only forcing a blocking call when you need to extract the data out (typically at `EnqueueReadBuffer()`). This way if you queue a series of kernels, they will run one after another with almost no idle time between them.

Comment: Yep i knew this way to measure GPU time execution with events. But isnt it a problem if i dont have the same time measurement reference (i compare a C implementation with an OpenCL one)? I will try it anyway to see the differences.